# pressing enter key and open a new form in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

When a user presses Enter key in one of my datagridview cells (like in column1 cells), a new form like form2 should be opened. I know that in the keypress event I should write `e.handled=true;` to achieve this, but this code is not working  when the datagridview cell is active. How can I do it?

Comment: The description you have provided here is some what confusious, please modify that to understand well.

Comment: excuse me, i cant speaking(and writing) english very well, i have one datagridview and 2 forms, i want when user write a code in one of datagridview cells (column 1 and any rows) and press Enter Key; form2 be shown.

Comment: The comment which you have given is very clear than your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the `EditingControlShowing` event of DataGridView control and `PreviewKeyDown` event of Cell's Control.

```
dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += (senderObject,eventArgs)=>
  {
    eventArgs.Control.PreviewKeyDown += (sa, ea) =>
      {
       if (ea.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
         {
           MessageBox.Show("Something...");
         }
      };
   };
```

Comment: thanks but this code dont working in other columns and open over than one instanc of form.

Answer (score 0):

hello  try to use this in below
create two form 
on form1 use the grid on given below name or as you can

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            testform tf = new testform();

            {
                if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Selected)
                {
                    if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "F1")

                    {
                        tf.Show();

                    }



                }
            }
```